# notifyOnItemChanged doesnot change border color and text

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I have a **gridlayout in recyclerview**.
A *single item has an imageview with a border and a textview*.
The *imageview has vector icon*.

On selecting(item click) an item, the color of image, border and text should change and the old item should go back to normal.
So only a *single selection should be possible*.

*Currently,the color of image only is changed for new and old one goes back to normal.*
*I cant achieve that with border and text.*

I am supposed to **use notifyItemChanged() and NOT notifyDataSetChanged()** for optimization purposes.

[image: Please check the image.]
On clicking add 8, it is highlighted but the old item add 6 should go back to normal. Like star goes normal but border and text doesnt.

**How to achieve same feat for border and text?**

Here is the code of adapter class that I tried.

```
      class imgAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<imgAdapter.viewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<String> mData;
    int selectedPos = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

    public imgAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = data;
    }

    //create holder
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        return new viewHolder(view,mData);
    }

    //bind the view to holder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(viewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.category.setText(mData.get(position));
        holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_black);
        holder.imgView.setSelected(selectedPos == position);
    }

    //get items size
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    //view Holder class
    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView category;
        ImageView imgView;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        int oldPos;

        public viewHolder(final View itemView, final List<String> mData) {
            super(itemView);
            category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
            imgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                        oldPos = selectedPos;
                        notifyItemChanged(selectedPos); //reset color of old position

                    DrawableCompat.setTint(imgView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorOrange));  //change color of selected position
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(imgView.getBackground(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorOrange));  //change border color of selected position
                    category.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F45642"));

                    selectedPos = getPosition();     // add new position as old position for next click

                    Toast.makeText(context, "old: " + oldPos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }


            });

        }
    }
}
```

XML of gridview single item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/star_black"
        android:tint="@color/colorGrey"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Categories"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

1. I am concerned that the notify changes only the image color and not the border color(which is set as background tint). **Do we have support of that with notify?**
2. Is there any method where we can manually set something like, setbackground where position == oldpos.
   i.e. Somethig like: **img[oldpos].setBackground()**

Comment: do call `notifyItemChanged` after all the code for color changes i.e. in your case after toast

Comment: @KapilRajput  Tried that. It will change color and remove color immediately. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

First create text_selector.xml image in drawable folder as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/red" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/red" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/gray" />
</selector>
```

Then Pass that "text_selector.xml" as textcolor in you recyclerview item for textview. Also you are calling notifyItemChanged only for old position and also you are not notifying new item change. so please change "itemView.setOnClickListener" as below:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(oldPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        notifyItemChanged(oldPos); //reset color of old position
                    }

                    oldPos = selectedPos;

                    DrawableCompat.setTint(imgView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorOrange));  //change color of selected position
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(imgView.getBackground(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorOrange));  //change border color of selected position
                    // category.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F45642"));
                    // comment this line and put text_selector drawable as textColor in xml

                    notifyItemChanged(selectedPos); //reset color of new position

                    selectedPos = getPosition();     // add new position as old position for next click

                    Toast.makeText(context, "old: " + oldPos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Then change your onBindViewHolder as below:

```
//bind the view to holder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(viewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.category.setText(mData.get(position));
        holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_black);
        if(selectedPos == position){
            holder.category.setSelected(true);
            holder.imgView.setSelected(true);   
        }else{
            holder.category.setSelected(false);
            holder.imgView.setSelected(false);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Tried that. The issue is not with notifyItemChange. The thing is that from the whole item, only image is changed and that is working perfectly. The border and text are not changing.

Comment: please provide your xml for recyclerview item

Comment: i have edited my answer for text only. you should do same for your parent view to change border with selector images as above